# how to write delete query in multiple selection?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I have a gridview in my web project and I connect it with the SqlDataSource. The select command contain fields from 3 table, and I created commandField for gridview so that users can delete their Purchase Items.
here is my C# select code:

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = 
    "SELECT Production.Name, Production.Price ,PurchaseItem.Quantity,
        Production.Info ,Purchase.OrderDate     
    FROM Production 
    INNER JOIN PurchaseItem on (Production.ID = PurchaseItem.ProductID) 
    INNER JOIN Purchase on(Purchase.ID = PurchaseItem.PurchaseID) 
    WHERE Purchase.UserID = '" + Convert.ToInt64(da.getuserid(Session["Mysys"].ToString()).FirstOrDefault()) + "'";
GridView1.DataSourceID = SqlDataSource1.ID;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

My problem is the DeleteCommand of the SqlDataSource.
is it Possible to do such thing?

Comment: where is delete command..?

Comment: Please add the delete portion you are referring to.

Comment: I just want to know is it possible by using the command field of the grid view and delete command of the sqldatasource to  write this query?

Comment: @MarioAna cause in the wizard mode you can do this thing with one table but not with more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Production, PurchaseItem, Purchase are the tables you want to delete the items by selecting on your gridview right? if so.

you just have to make a delete query like

```
DELETE FROM PRODUCTION WHERE ID = VALUE
DELETE FROM PURCHASEITEM WHERE ID = VALUE
DELETE FROM PURCHASE WHERE ID = VALUE
```

and if you want to delete running a single query only you may try INNER JOIN:

```
DELETE table1, table2  FROM table1  INNER JOIN table2  
WHERE table1.id=table2.id and table1.id = 'VALUE'
```